# Understanding log rotate configuration

Tags: linux, logrotate

I'm having difficulty understanding this logrotate file. Please correct me if I'm wrong

```
/var/log/app-logs
{
        daily
        rotate 7
        maxage 7
        dateext
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
        notifempty
        create 666 ubuntu ubuntu
}
```

`/var/log/app-logs` is going to be rotated daily(That day log file is compressed when the day finishes). logrotate will make sure there are not more than 7 compressed logs(.gz)
If there are any .gz files whose age > 7 days, they will be deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prediction is **correct**.

You can find perfect howto about logrorate [here](https://www.mybluelinux.com/how-manage-log-files-with-logrotate/)